# Using deep learning models from TensorFlow in other language environments

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a decent amount of experience with TensorFlow, and I am about to embark on a project which will ultimately culminate in using a TensorFlow trained model in a C# production environment. Essentially, I will have live data which will come into the C# environment, and I will ultimately need to output decisions / take certain actions based on the output of my model in TensorFlow. This is basically just a constraint of the existing infrastructure.

I can think of a couple of potentially bad ways to implement this, such as writing the data to disk and then calling the Python part of the application and then finally reading the result output by the Python application and taking some action based on it. This is slow, however.

Are there faster ways to accomplish this same integrated relationship between C# and the Python-based Tensorflow. I see that [there appear to be some ways](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) to do this with C++ and TensorFlow, but what about C#?

Comment: If you're talking about two applications on the same machine, why not use a simple TCP stream between the two?

Comment: Actually, that's a really good idea. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a prime use case for [TensorFlow Serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/), which lets you create a C++ process that can run inference on a trained TensorFlow model, and serves inference requests over [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/). You can write client code in any language that [gRPC supports](http://www.grpc.io/docs/). Take a look at the MNIST tutorial: [C++ server](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_inference_2.cc) and [Python client](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py) components.

Comment: I don't have much tensorflow experience, but for a project of mine I've been thinking of having my main application on .net core, and in a separate flask API, have all the code required to harness the power of deep learning in a separate python API that connects to the same database. Does anyone know which approach might be better?

Comment: Any update @mrry @carlos? Maybe cntk will soon be able to do the tf model import task?

Comment: Miguel de Icaza has been developing [TensorFlowSharp](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp), which provides .NET bindings to TensorFlow. It's probably the most full-fledged environment for C# programming with TensorFlow.